# Поиск блока кода с последующей заменой в SQL

Tags: php, sql

Всем привет. Нужно найти и поменять блок кода в БД.
Использую следующий запрос:

```
UPDATE `table_name` SET `field_name` = REPLACE(`field_name`, '<div id="wrap">
        <div class="block1">
            <div class="block2">
                {{chunk}}
            </div>
            {{chunk1}}
        </div>
    </div>', '{{replaceChunk}}')
```

Но запрос не срабатывает, так как блока код имеет переносы. Помогите создать запрос который будет учитывать переносы строк.
Спасибо.

Comment: укажите используемый SQL-сервер, в т.ч. его версию.

Comment: MySQL. Версия сервера: 5.5.35

Comment: Сочувствую. MySQL этой версии не имеет функции замены по регулярному выражению. Пишите пользовательскую функцию...

Comment: @Akina, спасибо за ответ))